# авторизация Symfony 4 username из двух полей

Tags: безопасность, авторизация, symfony

Стандартный компонент Security Symfony 4. поле username в форме авторизации составное. Первое поле код страны, второе телефон. Нужно до того, как symfony начнет процесс авторизации по сути username сложить в одну строку и дальше уже искать пользователя и авторизировать. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class LoginListener
{
   public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event){
     $request = $event->getRequest();

     if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST'
        && !empty($request->request->get('phoneCode'))
        && $request->request->get('phoneNumber')) {


        $phoneCode = $request->request->get('phoneCode');
        $phoneNumber = $request->request->get('phoneNumber');
        $username = $phoneCode . $phoneNumber;

        $request->request->set('_username', $username);       
     }
   }
}
```

это файл //src/EventListener/LoginListener.php

а также нужно зарегистрировать в #config/services.yaml

```
App\EventListener\LoginListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 255 }
```